# Compare the two rows of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an datset in which I want to find and display rows with any invalid data, e.g. the rate value is not in the range of MinCI and MaxCI, MinCI is larger than MaxCI, etc. If they exist, change the MinCI and MaxCI values in these
rows into NA.

```
   MinCI      MaxCI   City
    2.0        6.0    ABC
    4.2        8.0    XYZ
    3.6        1.2    CRS
    6.4        8.9    WUI
    7.8        5.4    IRK
```

So, in row 3 and 5 MinCI is greater than MaxCI so we want this columns value to be fill NA using R. For the complete column of the dataset

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical index and use that index to assign the column values to `NA`

```
i1 <- with(df1, MaxCI < MinCI)
df1[i1, c('MaxCI', 'MinCI')] <- NA
df1
#  MinCI MaxCI City
#1   2.0   6.0  ABC
#2   4.2   8.0  XYZ
#3    NA    NA  CRS
#4   6.4   8.9  WUI
#5    NA    NA  IRK
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(MinCI = c(2, 4.2, 3.6, 6.4, 7.8), MaxCI = c(6, 
8, 1.2, 8.9, 5.4), City = c("ABC", "XYZ", "CRS", "WUI", "IRK"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(MinCI:MaxCI, ~na_if(., MinCI < MaxCI)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  MinCI MaxCI City 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1   2     6   ABC  
2   4.2   8   XYZ  
3  NA    NA   CRS  
4   6.4   8.9 WUI  
5  NA    NA   IRK
```